# Uninitialized static object called simultaneously by two threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, static, static-methods

I have a couple of objects, each of them runs on its own thread, almost simultaneously those objects call another static object which have not been initialized, when I launch the `RunWorkerAsyc` function, the event `RunWorkerCompleted` returns with the error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
>   Message: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check InnerException for exception details.

If I only run one of the objects which use these uninitialized, the program works perfectly.

all of this is happening on Design mode, So I don't know how I could design my static class to avoid this. Were already tried the singleton approach, and we still get the same problem.

Any Ideas?

Stack trace

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
       at System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
       at HauxLifeSupport.SQL.SQLQueryRunnerBase._QueryWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in E:\NET\HLSToolKit2\HLSToolkitSQL\SQLQueryRunner.cs:line 83
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(HandleRef hWnd, String text, String caption, Int32 type)
       at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp)
       at System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String text)
       at HauxLifeSupport.SQL.SQLQueryRunnerBase._QueryWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in E:\NET\HLSToolKit2\HLSToolkitSQL\SQLQueryRunner.cs:line 78
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.LocalModalMessageLoop(Form form)
  InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
       Message=Could not load file or assembly 'HLSToolkitCommon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
       Source=HLSToolkitSQL
       FileName=HLSToolkitCommon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
       FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = HAUX1\garcia_luis
LOG: DisplayName = HLSToolkitCommon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: The same bind was seen before, and was failed with hr = 0x80070002.

       StackTrace:
            at HauxLifeSupport.SQL.SQLQueryRunnerBase._QueryWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
            at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Gonna need some code to see what's going wrong

Comment: should these 2 be able to use it at the same time, or should one be put on wait until First finished?
if only one is allowed you should use the lock keyword

Comment: Please paste the Inner Exception stack trace and message as it will contain all the info

Comment: @GoranŠtuc we lock the function so they don't use it at the same, The problem is the static object has not been initialized at that point.

Comment: @dbw There you can see the complete error message

Comment: FileNotFoundException - it's right there in the stack trace. HLSToolkitCommon.

Comment: @daveL I get that error only if call the static object in two threads, but if I run it only once, I get no error, that means that file is found, how can it be?

Comment: @daveL if I initialized the static object before calling any function of it, I dont have such an error, so that is not the problem.

Comment: Try using a singleton pattern to initialise this static variable

Comment: We are going to need to see how you initialise and share this variable.